# VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE upon startup and opening Google Chrome/Facebook

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod

Ever since I've had to reinstall Windows about two months ago, I once in a while get a BSOD, namely VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE. Upon looking it up, I have found out that things like bad cooling, a power supply, old drivers or a failing graphics card can cause this. Now, I have found that this only happens when I immediately after startup open Google Chrome and go on facebook. What I personally think then happens is that Chrome is loading videos on facebook, causing the graphics card driver to do something it doesn't like.

This is really annoying though (I guess something like that shouldn't happen), so I am looking for a solution to my problem. A "fix" suggested on a few websites is updating the graphics card drivers, but mine are already up to date.

To try and give you the most information possible, I am going to give you my specs (as much as I can find right now):

- OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64
- CPU: Intel Core i5-4670T CPU @ 2.30GHz
- GPU: ASUS R9 270 Series
- Main board: MSI H87M-G43
- Power supply: BQ L8-500W (I think, not sure)

Minidump information:

```
VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE (116)
Attempt to reset the display driver and recover from timeout failed.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa80079da010, Optional pointer to internal TDR recovery context (TDR_RECOVERY_CONTEXT).
Arg2: fffff88003e0ae80, The pointer into responsible device driver module (e.g. owner tag).
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Optional error code (NTSTATUS) of the last failed operation.
Arg4: 0000000000000002, Optional internal context dependent data.
FAULTING_IP: 
atikmpag+ae80
fffff880`03e0ae80 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  GRAPHICS_DRIVER_TDR_FAULT
CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x116
PROCESS_NAME:  System
CURRENT_IRQL:  0
STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`04df1888 fffff880`04072134 : 00000000`00000116 fffffa80`079da010 fffff880`03e0ae80 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`04df1890 fffff880`04071e3e : fffff880`03e0ae80 fffffa80`079da010 fffffa80`0916b0b0 fffffa80`07bce410 : dxgkrnl!TdrBugcheckOnTimeout+0xec
fffff880`04df18d0 fffff880`04119f13 : fffffa80`079da010 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0916b0b0 fffffa80`07bce410 : dxgkrnl!TdrIsRecoveryRequired+0x1a2
fffff880`04df1900 fffff880`04143cf1 : 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`0000146c 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 : dxgmms1!VidSchiReportHwHang+0x40b
fffff880`04df19e0 fffff880`04142437 : 00000000`00000102 00000000`00000006 00000000`0000146c 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms1!VidSchiCheckHwProgress+0x71
fffff880`04df1a10 fffff880`041152d2 : ffffffff`ff676980 fffffa80`07bce410 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms1!VidSchiWaitForSchedulerEvents+0x1fb
fffff880`04df1ab0 fffff880`04141ff6 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`085e9d50 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`07bce410 : dxgmms1!VidSchiScheduleCommandToRun+0x1da
fffff880`04df1bc0 fffff800`03160926 : 00000000`00c9a815 fffffa80`07b9c060 fffffa80`0664db10 fffffa80`07b9c060 : dxgmms1!VidSchiWorkerThread+0xba
fffff880`04df1c00 fffff800`02eb90e6 : fffff800`03047e80 fffffa80`07b9c060 fffff800`03055cc0 fffffa80`07bf5430 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`04df1c40 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
STACK_COMMAND:  .bugcheck ; kb
FOLLOWUP_IP: 
atikmpag+ae80
fffff880`03e0ae80 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
SYMBOL_NAME:  atikmpag+ae80
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: atikmpag
IMAGE_NAME:  atikmpag.sys
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  52311556
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x116_IMAGE_atikmpag.sys
BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x116_IMAGE_atikmpag.sys
Followup: MachineOwner
```

My question is: Is there Anything you can tell me with the information I provided about which cause is the most likely and what would be the next steps to take?

Comment: try the latest driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows+7+-+64

Comment: @magicandre1981 Interesting. I downloaded it, applied it and restarted my PC a few times to see if anything has changed. I do not get a BSOD anymore, there don't seem to be any further problems. I am kind of mad the solution was so easy, yet Windows claimed that the drivers installed were the latest available so that I did not even consider downloading anything. Had you posted this as an answer, I would have accepted it.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the data that you've posted I can see that [Bugcheck 0x116](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was caused by the AMD GPU driver `atikmpag.sys`.

Go to the [AMD website, download](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%207%20-%2064) and install the latest driver version.